# ln -s not working under /mnt/

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora, amazon-ebs, symbolic-link

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.john-nousis.com/development/tutorial-running-a-phpmysql-server-on-ec2-with-ebs/) to set up a LAMP stack on EC2 with persistent storage on EBS. It all works well when doing it step by step.

But in case you want to mount your EBS under /mnt instead of under the root directory the

```
ln -s
```

commands won't work!

I tried:

```
ln -s /mnt/ebs1/httpd /etc
```

and:

```
ln -s /mnt/ebs1/httpd /etc/httpd
```

Is there a difference when linking to a file on a device that is mounted under /mnt?

(working on fedora core 8)

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?  Is there an error message?

Comment: David, thanks for your query, no there is no error in the command line after submitting the links. but when i start back the httpd service i get an error saying that the .conf file is unreadable and the service fail to start.

Comment: What do you see when you do `ls -l /mnt/ebs1/httpd /etc`?

Comment: Yaniv, what is the result of `ls -ld /etc/httpd` ? This may seem obvious, but the obvious has to be covered....

Comment: Please don't try to symlink your entire /etc to a httpd config directory. It will kill your system. ln -s /mnt/ebs1/httpd /etc/httpd should work, unless there already is a /etc/httpd present.

Answer (score 1):

`ln -s /path/to/source /path/to/dest`

should work on any normal filesystem.

What do you see with `ls -lh /mnt/ebs1/httpd`? Is the symlink created? If it is, check if apache is allowed to open the directory and read the config files. To do so, enter `ls -l /mnt/ebs1/` and look for "x" and "r" bits in the permissions (beginning of line).

**Update after comment:**

The permissions are okay AFAIK. You should focus on apache then. Are there any errors in the logs? What does debug say?

Comment: Thanks PEra, 
output for ls -lh /mnt/ebs/httpd:

# ls -lh /mnt/ebs1/httpd
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K 2009-10-31 19:27 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K 2009-10-31 19:27 conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   19 2009-10-31 19:32 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 2009-10-31 19:32 modules -> ../../usr/lib/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 2009-10-31 19:32 run -> ../../var/run

and for ls -l /mnt/ebs1/ i get:

# ls -l /mnt/ebs1/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 2009-10-31 19:27 httpd
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 2009-10-31 19:25 lost+found

any suggestions?

Comment: sorry for that mess :)

Comment: well... 
i can't access the logs i see the file when i dir httpd but i cant see it's content with vi (says ne file)..

Answer (score 0):

/mnt is usually for external drives like cdroms and usb sticks.  USB sticks, phones, ipods etc. usually have crappy filesystems that don't support features like links.

Comment: i formated the device to ext3
using;
 mkfas ext3 /dev/sdh
and mounted it with:
 mount -t ext3 /dev/sdh /mnt/ebs1

is that change anything?

Comment: The /media directory is used for removable media such as iPods, USB sticks, etc.  The /mnt directory is for system administrator use.  See the FHS specifications (part of the LSB spec):
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT

Furthermore, while most removable devices do use FAT, which is not suitable for links, the end result of the OP's link is in /etc, for which links must work on most Unix systems.

Comment: /mnt used to be a dir for mountpoints a couple of years ago... I guess that old habits die slowly.

Comment: Oh, right, never mind then :D